# Getting Firebase documents inside a range

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

I created a chat app where I display the messages to the users.

So far, when users join a chat it shows them the last 50 messages by using the following:

```
db.collection("Chats")
        .orderBy("SentTime", Query.Direction.ASCENDING).limitToLast( 50 )
        .addSnapshotListener(listener);
```

Now, I had like to add an option where the users can scroll up in the recyclerView and once they reached the top of these 50 messages it will load another older 50 messages.

So I thought to use something like

```
db.collection("Chats")
        .orderBy("SentTime", Query.Direction.ASCENDING).startsAt(X).endsat(Y)
        .addSnapshotListener(listener);
```

So I wonder if there is an option to do this startsAt/EndAt where I have control over the 50 messages?

Or if there is better way to load everytime the previous 50 messages it will be helpful.

Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "where I have control over the 50 messages".  Are you trying to do pagination?  https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors

Comment: It is what im trying to do but I can either use limit(50) where it will always give me only the last 50 or endAt() startAt() but the values I need to put in them is a value of my field and not the number of documents in my collection. I want to use endAt(last item in collection) startAt(last item - 50).

Comment: I think you just want to use limit.  There is no way to say "endAt(last item in collection)".

Comment: Yes, but then it will give me only the last 50. I want the 50 items before the last 50.

Comment: Change the direction of the sort, or use endBefore.

Comment: endBefore(field value) no? I need endBefore(index of document)

Comment: You can't use indexes.  You have to use a DocumentSnapshot from the prior query.

Comment: that guy is explaining pagination nicely https://youtu.be/HQgJvHXsNOQ

Comment: See that you are trying to paginate the results and to have real-time updates. So if you are interested in a Firestore real-time pagination algorithm you can take a look at this [example](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirestoreRealtimePagination), which is a repo for this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-a-clean-firestore-pagination-with-real-time-updates-ce05a87bb902).